# ReactiveUI Bind an Enum Property to a Color Property in View Model

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I am starting my first Reactive UI Project. I have an enum, and I want to map a specific color to a specific enum value. How could I accomplish this using Reactive UI? So when Status changes the TextColor changes.

Say I wanted to map

- Running -> Green
- Idle -> Orange
- Faulted -> Red
- Manual -> Blue

Here is my View Model

```
public enum Status { Running, Idle, Faulted, Manual}

public class MachineStatusViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public string Name;
    public Status Status;
    public System.Drawing.Color TextColor;

    public MachineStatusViewModel()
    {           

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better approach is to use the OneWayBind operator over WhenAnyValue

`this.OneWayBind(this.ViewModel, vm => vm.Status, view => view.TextColor, GetColor);`

```cs
private Color GetColor(Status status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case Status.Running:
            return Color.Green;
        case Status.Idle:
            return Color.Orange;
        case Status.Faulted:
            return Color.Red;
        case Status.Manual:
            return Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why is it a better approach?

Comment: Couple reasons, you can use a registered global binding. So you don't have to repeat the conversion all the time. So if you are using the binding in more than one place it'll reduce the amount of code you have to use. See https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/value-converters for a example. There is also some caching in terms of the value converters which can give you small amounts of gain.

Comment: So potentially what you could do is have a `IBindingTypeConverter` you register once for Status -> Color, and you'll only need to register it once within your application then whenever you use the Bind/OneWayBind operators it'll know how to handle those cases from there onwards.

Comment: Would this still be done in the ViewModel or would this be done in the view?

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to go with resource dictionary. It can allow you to substitute one dictionary with another or define themed resources easily without hardcoding values to return. Simple example for your case:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="Running.Color" G="255"/>
    <Color x:Key="Idle.Color" R="255" G="165"/>
    <Color x:Key="Faulted.Color" R="255"/>
    <Color x:Key="Manual.Color" B="255"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then you use this dictionary in your view's xaml as a merged one (i.e. in Window)

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/<AssemblyName>;component/<Resource-Dictionary-File>.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

And the usage:

```cs
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.Status)
    .Select(x => FindResource($"{x}.Color"))
    .BindTo(this, view => view.TextColor);
```